# Need to remove the slash ( / ) from the end of the url with nginx

Tags: nginx

Here, I am redirecting all the urls to https://www.example.com

but when I trying to remove the / from the https://www.example.com/test/ it's giving
Too_many_redirect issue and creating infinite loop of redirection.

File is below:

```
    server {
    server_name example.com; 
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9003;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
 }

    server {
        server_name www.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9003;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    merge_slashes off;
    rewrite ^(/.*?)/+$ $1 permanent;

}

    server {
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
      }
```

I have also tried placing below:

```
    rewrite ^(.+)/index.html$ $1 permanent;
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems like your application at `http://127.0.0.1:9003` is probably redirecting `/test` to `/test/`

Comment: Yes, It was a gatsby application. Thanks.

Comment: Here is the answer. 

https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-remove-trailing-slashes/